# In Doctor McCoy's sickbay bed monitors on the Enterprise, what are the units used on the measurement gauges?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

Based on [In Doctor McCoy's sickbay bed monitors on the Enterprise, what is "Cell Rate?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259316/in-doctor-mccoys-sickbay-bed-monitors-on-the-enterprise-what-is-cell-rate), the answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/259325/3804) gives a list of what the gauges are for.

However the units listed either don't make sense, or are not ones I recognise.

The ones with non-standard units are reproduced below, from the linked answer:

> - **Brain [K3](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/K3_indicator)** - Displays the electrical activity of the brain - extreme
>   activity may indicate high levels of pain
> - **Blood Q⁵**; Displays the heart activity, notably its electrical stimulus (beat), which is actually two pumping actions (in count/minute)
> - **Blood T²×10** - Displays the mean diastolic blood pressure (in mmHg), for use in diagnosing hyper or hypotension.

So besides [K3](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/K3_indicator), the unexplained units are *Q⁵* and *T²×10*. But the units of pressure should be N/m², and 'count' would be unitless making that even harder to understand.

What are these units?

Comment: They're handwavium units to stop people calling them out for being wrong or dangerous in a clinical environment.

Comment: A fictional universe need not have real units of measure.

Comment: Q often represents electrical charge in equations, measured in units of C (Coulombs) - but Q to the fifth power makes little sense.